# Add an MD5 index to a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a table in a Postgresql database with a column containing large texts.
I ran into this problem:

```
HINT:  Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.
Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.
```

So I want to add a MD5 index to this table. 
I found how to do so in PG, but not in with ActiveRecord. Any idea on how to do this in a migration? Will my queries use this index by default or do I need to rewrite a bunch of them ?

Comment: You can run arbitrary SQL in migrations

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks, like execute(...) ? 
Will this index be used if I query this column in the future like this:
Table.where(large_text_column: "abc")

Comment: "Will this index be used..." - haven't worked with md5 indexes, so no idea :)

Comment: Nope, they won't work. But this: `Table.where('md5(large_text_column) = md5(?)', "abc")` will use md5 index.
More info: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/functions/case-insensitive-search